# Science fiction anthology, possibly called Monsters (or Creatures or Dragons)?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I am trying to recall an anthology of science fiction short stories I read about 15-20 years ago.  It was called "Monsters" or something similar (could have been "Creatures" or "Dragons" or something else, I don't precisely recall).  The theme was monsters and creatures in science fiction (not any fantasy-type stories I think).  The story I specifically remember involved humans exploring an alien planet and encountering a unique creature there.  The creature was harmless when first encountered but at each subsequent encounter the creature had changed and adapted to its environment and the human threat - it was hyper-evolving and quickly becoming a life-threatening danger.  I don't recall how the story resolved but I think the humans "won".

Does anyone recall this story or anthology?  I checked ISFDB but could not find anything that matched up to what I recall.

Comment: The title suggests it might be one of the anthologies edited by [Gardner Dozois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardner_Dozois)

Comment: The thematic Dozois anthologies seem very close to what I remember. I think user14111 hit on it with Asimov tho.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story you remember sounds like ["Student Body"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46230) by [F. L. Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._L._Wallace) (first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, March 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58578+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v05n06_1953-03.Galaxy/Galaxy%20v05n06%20%281953-03.Galaxy%29#page/n79/mode/2up)), which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60149/short-story-about-human-colonists-vs-alien-animals-that-evolve-very-rapidly). You can read the [Project Gutenberg etext](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31815) or listen to the [*X Minus One* radio dramatization](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne56-07-31062StudentBody.mp3). The anthology you're looking for is probably the Asimov-Greenberg-Waugh-edited [*Monsters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178677), published in 1988.

Comment: I think you are correct!  The story is very similar to what I recall and the anthology cover seems quite familiar.  To be honest the story as I remember it is different in some ways from "Student Body" but I have a feeling that is due to the fog of time.  Thank you.