# Planet of animals that evolve in minutes

Tags: story-identification, evolution

Looking for a story that starts with quasi-intelligent life on an alien planet that evolve due to environmental pressure in minutes. All except for this one super-creature, who would defeat all others. It never had the 'urge to evolve'. Until one day a ship lands (humans as I recall) and is able to kill/defeat everything including the super-creature. Only then did it get the 'urge to evolve'.  I read this between 2000 and 2010, but I think its much older.

I vaguely recall "Evolve" or "Evolution" in the title and the story narrative is 100% from the alien's perspective.

Comment: There's a story of incredibly rapid evolution referenced in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60149/short-story-about-human-colonists-vs-alien-animals-that-evolve-very-rapidly but it had basically one species that kept evolving, and no "super-creature".

Comment: @SeanDuggan No.. not that one, this story narrative is 100% from the alien's perspective. I vaguely recall "Evolve" or "Evolution" in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "Mutation Planet" (1973) by Barrington J. Bayley in [Knights of the Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knights_of_the_Limits)
It can be read at [Mutation Planet](http://weirdfictionreview.com/2015/06/mutation-planet/)

> Filled with ominous mutterings, troubled by ground-trembling rumblings, the vast and brooding landscape stretched all around in endless darkness and gloom. Across this landscape the mountainous form of *Dominus* moved at speed, a massed, heavy shadow darker than the gloom itself, sullenly majestic, possessing total power.

I had forgotten the actual words for near the ending, they are:

> With that realization an urge beyond all power to resist came upon *Dominus*: the *compulsion* to evolve.

I must give all credit to [Hypnosfil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22250/hypnosifl)
It's only because (s)he remembered the answer to the [Chess Knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108534/alien-communication-via-a-chess-knight-piece/108536#108536) question I was able to track this down. Thanks so much bud.